# How to control color of particle instances (hair) that are objects, not paths?

Tags: materials, particles

When I want to control color of hair that are just paths, it's simple. I paint the emitter in vertex paint mode, then in the particle material I use vertex color node:

[image: paths material]

[image: vertex color]

However, when hair are objects (for example grass strands), they have their own materials. The material for them can not be selected in the emitter. So how can I get vertex color data from the emitter into the material of another object, namely a different mesh that is used as particle instances? I would like to color them based on the vertex paint of the emitter.

[image]

EDIT: I'm using Blender 2.90 alpha and Eevee as render engine. In Cycles I could use Texture Coordinate node with "From Instancer" option checked, but it doesn't seem to work in Eevee.

Comment: Now I believe you can use the Geometry Nodes Attribute and combine what you want. That's something I wanted to do back then and it was not possible. Unfortunately I haven't tested it yet.